# What does this painting's signature say? (Characters identified: 姜旗)

Tags: character-identification

See picture below.  It also has the letters J . Q

[image: Signarure on painting]

Comment: The character on the left is 羌 /Qiang/, not sure what the character on the right is, possibly 冿 /jiān/

Comment: the left character is 姜（jiang）. I cannot determine the other one. The dark background makes it difficult to tell the strokes. Is it shadow? Or can you provide a high contrast version?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to think it is 姜琪（JIANG QI）. Though 王 is odd, 其 is quite obvious.

Edit:

@Sylvia is right: It's 姜旗, though the stroke order of 方 is incorrect.

Comment: I think it's 姜旗

Comment: Thank You, correct and led me to this art site:

Comment: https://www.clatia.com/artist/index/174-1